# Need to ssh from one Amazon EC2 server into another one

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Basically I need to be able to connect from one [EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance to another using SSH. I run the command `ssh -i path-to-pem-file ec2-user@dns-address-of-ec2-instance`, and it times out.

I set my security group to allow SSH inbound from the public IP address of my second EC2 instance, but it still doesn't work. I know that everything should be fine because when I set my SSH  inbound traffic to "allow from anywhere" I can connect with no problems. Also I can connect to the EC2 instance from a home machine (I added my IP address to the security group) without any problems.

Obviously I can't leave my inbound traffic open to "allow from anywhere", but I can't seem to connect when I limit it to just the IP address of the second EC2 instance. Maybe the public IP address isn't what I should be putting into the security group?

---

I can't seem to ping it either; it just times out. Here is the result of `ssh -vv -i path-to-pem-file ec2-user@dns-address-of-ec2-instance`

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1h-fips 5 Jun 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ec2-user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to dns-address [IP Address different from public ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address [IP Address different from public ip] port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host dns-address port 22: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EC2 instances use an internal `10.X.X.X` address (or other address if using a VPC), and traffic to their 'public' IP address is simply re-routed to the internal IP address. EC2 instances also use a different DNS server that is not publicly accessible. When you resolve the hostname of the other EC2 instance, because you're inside the [AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) network, it gives you the instance's `10.X.X.X` address instead of the public IP address. This prevents the traffic from having to go out to the internet and back in, which makes it faster.

Even if you could whitelist by IP address, this isn't a good idea as in EC2 classic mode, both your internal and public address can change. The proper solution is to whitelist by security group. You basically add a rule to the destination security group saying to allow port 22 from a specific origin security group.

If both instances are in the same account, you simply allow `sg-1234abcd` (where `sg-1234abcd` is the security group the origin instance is a member of). If they are in different accounts, include the account number, such as `111122223333/sg-1234abcd`.
See [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules) for additional information.

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what I was looking for! Works without a hitch!

Comment: When speaking of security groups of different accounts, you need to make VPC peering so that you can reference them. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-security-groups.html

Comment: Just for completion, I wanted to add that AWS charges you for incoming traffic to a VPC from the internet, but traffic inside the VPC is free, so not going through the internet is not only faster but also cheaper.